# How to check the file is used by another process?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, spfile

In sharepoint from Document library i was read the file and Download the file using FileStream object. Sometime it was downloading. Sometime i will receive the following error.

The process cannot access the file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\  because it is being used by another process.

My code :

```
 SPListItem item = DownLoadfile(strID, strListID, "AllowEmailShare");



            if (item != null)
            {
                byte[] obuffer;
                SPFile stFile = item.File;

                if (stFile.LockType != SPFile.SPLockType.None)

                {

                    stFile.ReleaseLock(stFile.LockId);

                }
                //IsFileinUse(oSPFile)
                // if (!IsFileLocked(oSPFile))
                if (stFile != null)
                {


                    //obuffer = oSPFile.OpenBinary();
                    using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(stFile.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {

                        byte[] Data = stFile.OpenBinary(); //in this l ine i was receiving the error
                        if (Data != null)
                        {
                            sr.Write(Data, 0, Data.Count());
                            sr.Close();
                            sr.Dispose();
                            string strUrl = stFile.Web.Url + "/" + stFile.Url;

                            this.Page.Response.Clear();
                            this.Page.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                            this.Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + Convert.ToString(item["Name"]));
                            //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
                            //BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(outStream);
                            //bw.Write(fileData);
                            //bw.Close();

                            this.Page.Response.BinaryWrite(Data);
                            this.Page.Response.Flush();
                            this.Page.Response.Close();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check if the handle of the file is being used to achieve it.

Here is the code of how to check handle of file for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplicationCommon
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of UseAPI.
    /// </summary>
    public class UseAPI
    {

        private const int OF_READWRITE = 2;
        private const int OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x40;
        private static readonly IntPtr HFILE_ERROR = new IntPtr(-1);


        /// <summary>
        /// get the handle of file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpPathName">file path</param>
        /// <param name="iReadWrite"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr _lopen(string lpPathName, int iReadWrite);

        /// <summary>
        /// close file handle
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hObject"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        /// <summary>
        /// check if the file is being used
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">file path</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsOpen(string filePath)
        {
            IntPtr vHandle = _lopen(filePath, OF_READWRITE | OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE);
            if (vHandle == HFILE_ERROR)
            {
                CloseHandle(vHandle);
                return true;
            }
           else
            {
                CloseHandle(vHandle);
                return false;
            }              
        }
    }
```

}

Screenshot of result:
[image]